# Grub fails to boot Arch OS on Raid-10

Tags: grub, arch-linux, mdadm

I have no problem to put Arch OS onto a regular disk.  But, when I used Raid-10 disk and boot it, grub loader will say: "ERROR: device 'UUID=7a6a787c-81bc-47b9-bdad-663c1d6b2a2b'".  The UUID shown is my Raid-10's.  Then boot stops and puts me in emergency shell.

---

I finally figured out how to do it:

1. `vi /etc/mkinitcpio.conf`; lines to be changed

   ```
   HOOKS=HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck mdadm_udev)
   BINARIES=(/sbin/mdmon)
   ```
2. `mkinitcpio -p Linux`, to generate a new `vmlinuz-linux` and `initramfs-linux.img` to include mdadm support

And I did bring up a Raid-10 far02 in XFS format running Arch OS.

If anybody is interested, I will provide more details of it.

Comment: Why was this closed? It's not off-topic. At most the title is poorly worded and I submitted a edit to correct that. The actually question itself falls well within community guidelines.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, but as the answer is now in the question body the whole thing's a bit of a mess. Once reopened can we separate out the answer properly?

Comment: Please [do not edit your original question to include an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216722/271445). Instead, post an answer on your question.

Comment: AlexLai: Your question has been reopened, so answers can be posted again. Please post your solution ***as an answer*** and then remove it from the question.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: It seems a little mean-spirited to tell the OP to post an answer on their question when you know they can’t.

Comment: @G-Man It's not meant to be mean. Answers shouldn't be posted in a question, regardless of whether the question is closed or not. Nevertheless, when I made my comment the question had 4 reopen votes so I knew by the time the OP saw my comment he'd be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

1. vi /etc/mkinitcpio.conf; lines to be changed:

HOOKS=HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck mdadm_udev)
BINARIES=(/sbin/mdmon)

2. mkinitcpio -p Linux, to generate a new vmlinuz-linux and initramfs-linux.img to include mdadm support

And I did bring up a Raid-10 far02 in XFS format running Arch OS.